# configuring network files in windows 10 linux bash shell

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, windows

just wondering what are the right files to configure the network in windows 10 bash shell, internet works anyway, here is the last error I got from net manager

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/interfaces: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl restart snapd.service` fix it? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `root@astral-cosmic:/mnt# systemctl restart snapd.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).                                       Can't operate.
root@astral-cosmic:/mnt# ls -a
.  ..  c
root@astral-cosmic:/mnt#`

Comment: there is no mnt for network